# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontawesomefree'

Tags: python, django, font-awesome

I am getting this error when I try to import fonrawesomefree icons to my django project. I used official [django docs](https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/docs/web/use-with/python-django)

requirements.txt file have following

```
# some other requirements
fontawesomefree==5.15.4
```

settings.py have following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # some other installed apps
    'fontawesomefree',
]
```

base.html file have following

```
<head>
     #some other link & script files
     <link href="{% static 'fontawesomefree/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css">
</head>
```

Project structure

```
[projectname]/
├── [projectname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
|
|── [App1]
|── [static]/ 
|   ├── [css]
|   ├── [Javascript]
|   └── [Images]
|
|── [templates]
|── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

When I try to run server I get following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontawesomefree'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you install `fontawesomefree` with the package manager (for example `pip3`), for example `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: thank you Williem that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a package to the `requirements.txt` is *not* enough. The `requirements.txt` file is just a list of packages that you want to install.

You need a package manager, like `pip3`, or the package manager of your virtual environment to download the package, and run the installation script.

You can install the `fontawesomefree` and other packages listed for example with `pip3` by running the following command in the shell:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

or look up how to install packages with your package manager.